# Импортировать файлы из другой папки python

Tags: python, файлы, импорт, python-telegram-bot, python-import

Всем привет, я не понимаю как импортировать py файлы с разных папок, пример:
в папке `1` лежит `main.py`, рядом есть папка `2` и в папке `2` лежит `call.py`
Мне нужно импортировать `main.py` в `call.py`.
Код ``main.py```

```
bot = Bot(token=token, parse_mode="HTML")
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
```

Код `call.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
from main import bot, dp
```

Код ошибки

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'bot' from partially initialized module 'main' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\proj\zayavkiBot\..\main.py)
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: только прописывать в окружении путь до второй папки. Импорт не позволяет указывать пути

Comment: sys.path.append('путь')  - теперь можно импортировать модуль

Comment: @Виктор а как мне перейти в предыдущую папку, например я нахожусь в dir1/main/ а нужно перейти в dir1/ как это сделать?

Comment: Перейти на уровень вверх " ../ "

Comment: @Виктор не помогло

Comment: @XotteiKottei Я не телепат:) Кусок кода, что Вы хотите проделать. Добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @Виктор Добавил!